# Ruby on Rails 4 Password Validation

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

Having an existing validation on password field that works fine.

```
PASSWORD_FORMAT = /\A
  (?=.{8,})          # Must contain 8 or more characters
  (?=.*\d)           # Must contain a digit
  (?=.*[a-z])        # Must contain a lower case character
  (?=.*[A-Z])        # Must contain an upper case character
  (?=.*[[:^alnum:]]) # Must contain a symbol
/x

validates :password, presence: true, format: {with: PASSWORD_FORMAT}
```

Now I want to to add one more condition: Password cannot contain repeating or sequential characters of 3 or more (ex. 123, abc, zzz, 555).

How can I add this to existing regular expression ?

Comment: Why don't you let people choose their own password?

Comment: You could split all character and test in a loop that next character is not consecutive from the previous.

Comment: Isn't it possible in current regex ?

Comment: You could just test is there is no repeated character with: `(?!.*(.)\1\1)` but sequential characters, it is much longer to code (ie. `(?!abc|bcd|cde|.....)`)

Comment: Useful tool for helping you with the regex generation: http://regexr.com/

Comment: I know this is irrelevant to the question but may I know what does /x means in this regexp?